# Qlikview - data from excel

Tags: excel, charts, qlikview

i have specific table that i fill every day and i need to create bar chart from this table.

My table loook like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Column C,D,E,F present one week in month and i need to fill data from SmallPlace, BigPlace,All and Date. Column G,H,I,J present next week with data.

I need to load this excel in qlikview and

- make chart that have x-axis column smallPlace,BigPlace and sum of
  row,
- also need chart that can filter by date,
- chart for sum of all       total by day,
- chart for all    smallPlace,BigPlace from column C,D ,G,H.

I don't have any idea. Can I create chart with table like this or I need to change my table???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From data perspective the structure in the excel file is hard to process. If you have control over the excel file i can suggest you to change it on something that is easy to be loaded (not only in QV)

The script below will load the data and will convert it to something that then can be used to build charts much easier. Also you can download the qvw that ive used from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjGsOE_3VoOVktPaUpDa0pMOWs/view?usp=sharing)

**P.S. Im using QV version 12.1**

```
// Load only the first record to get the available column names
Metadata:
First 1
Load 
  *
From 
  [C:\Users\Home\Documents\Book1.xlsx] (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1)
;

// Get the total column names - 1 (will exclude the Day column
let sColumnsCount = NoOfFields('Metadata') - 1;

// How many iterations. 5 is the step 
let sStep = $(sColumnsCount) / 5;

for i = 0 to $(sColumnsCount) - 1 step 5

  // Get the column names for each iteration
  let sDay              = FieldName( 1, 'Metadata' );
  let sLocationField    = FieldName( $(i) + 2, 'Metadata' );
  let sSmallPlaceField  = FieldName( $(i) + 3, 'Metadata' );
  let sBigPlaceField    = FieldName( $(i) + 4, 'Metadata' );
  let sAllField         = FieldName( $(i) + 5, 'Metadata' );
  let sDateField        = FieldName( $(i) + 6, 'Metadata' );

  // Load only the colums from the iteration
  // and append it to the main table
  Data:
  Load
    $(sDay)                as Day,
    $(sLocationField)      as Location,
    $(sSmallPlaceField)    as SmallPlace,
    $(sBigPlaceField)      as BigPlace,
    //$(sAllField)           as All, // <-- Dont think you need this
    $(sDateField)          as Date             
  FROM 
    [C:\Users\Home\Documents\Book1.xlsx] (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1)
  Where
    lower( $(sLocationField) ) <> 'total' // <-- think that the Total values are not needed as well
  ;

next

Drop Table Metadata;
```

Comment: When i run code i got error :  Syntax error, missing/misplaced FROM:
Data:
  Load
    Day                as Day,
    SmallPlace1      as Location,
    BigPlace1    as SmallPlace,
    All1      as BigPlace,
    Date1           as All, 
              as Date             
  FROM 
   [C:\Users\Loc.xlsx]  (ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1)
  Where
    lower( SmallPlace1 ) <> 'total'                                                             It looks like in variable sLocationField put value from SmallPlace1???? and Data is empty

Comment: I don't understand why you put step 5? What means this step 5?

Comment: I've tried to recreate the same excel as the one form the screenshot and probably im might missed something. If you can upload sample data somewhere i can look into it.